# Add CSS classes to blog images via ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've added a set of border stylings to my media attachment page using Advanced Custom Fields. What I want is to be able to select one of these options and add the relevant style as a class to the attached image.

**For example:** a blogger can create a post and mix and match different stylings to the images without knowing any CSS or HTML. I've attached a screenshot of the attachment page.

I've been investigating this and it seems like it has to do with `attachment_fields_to_edit` or `attachment_fields_to_save` filters, but I can't put it all together.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpQ5Q.jpg

So ideally, if I were to select the Green Border option the image in the post would have a "green-border" class.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I'm misunderstanding the question, but could you not just do:

```
    <?php
    $style = get_field('border_options');
    ?>

    <div class="<?php echo $style . '-border'; ?>">
        Content
    </div>
```

?